# Making HTTP get request to an api in dart only?

Tags: dart

Hey I wanted to know how to make a HTTP request to an api or webpage in dart language only not combined with flutter,like `requests.get()` in python .

Comment: It's actually pretty much the same, since they're both using dart:io's http routines.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `http` package: https://pub.dev/packages/http

A simple example (not dealing with errors...):

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

main() async {
  var response = await http.get('http://www.google.com');
  print(response.body);
}
```

The example in the README:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = 'https://example.com/whatsit/create';
var response = await http.post(url, body: {'name': 'doodle', 'color': 'blue'});
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');

print(await http.read('https://example.com/foobar.txt'));
```